# Returning 404 with redirecting?

Tags: lighttpd

This is my entire lighttpd config file:

```
var.log_root    = "/var/log/"

var.state_dir   = "/var/run"
var.home_dir    = "/var/lib/lighttpd"
var.conf_dir    = "/etc/lighttpd"
var.socket_dir  = home_dir + "/sockets"

server.modules = (
  "mod_rewrite"
)

server.port = 80

server.use-ipv6 = "disable"


server.pid-file = state_dir + "/lighttpd.pid"
server.errorlog             = log_root + "/error.log"

$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    url.redirect ="(.*)" => "https://%1/")
}
```

For some reason, I get a 404 when I try to access the server. All I want to do is redirect everything to https://{hostname}/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the error.log, in your case /var/log/error.log

You are using `url.redirect`, but do not appear to be loading mod_redirect in `server.modules`.  You need mod_redirect instead of mod_rewrite.  The lighttpd error log is probably reporting that `url.redirect` is an unknown directive since you have not loaded mod_redirect.

Also, `server.document-root` does not appear to be specified, and so there should be trace in the error log for that, too.